# EditText visible when selected Spinner

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner, visibility

I have a spinner with a list of two items in @ strings.

I want that when User A to select the item becomes visible editbox.

When you select item B be invisible again.

thank you!

Comment: I am honestly wholeheartedly trying to understand what you mean there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    switch (position) {
                    case 1:
                        // set editbox visible
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // set editbox invivible
                        break;

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // set editbox invivible

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) to get the position of the selected item. according to position visible or invisible the textview